# using RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba vs RandomForestRegressor.predict

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a data set comprising a vector of features, and a target - either 1.0 or 0.0 (representing two classes). If I fit a  `RandomForestRegressor` and call its `predict` function, is it equivalent to using `RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba()`?

In other words if the target is 1.0 or 0.0 does `RandomForestRegressor` output probabilities?

I think so, and the results I a m getting suggest so, but I would like to get a second opinion...

Thanks
Weasel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a major conceptual diffrence between those, based on different tasks being addressed:

*Regression*: continuous (real-valued) target variable.

*Classification*: discrete target variable (classes).

For a general classification method, term `probability of observation being class X` may be not defined, as some classification methods, `knn` for example, do not deal with probabilities.

However for Random Forest (and some other classification methods), classification is reduced to regression of classes probabilities destibution. Predicted class is taked then as argmax of computed "probabilities". In your case, you feed the same input, you get the same result. And yes, it is ok to treat values returned by `RandomForestRegressor` as probabilities.

Comment: Actually  Random Forest classification cannot be reduced to regression of classes probabilities distribution. Individual decision trees are natural categorical classifiers and the probability distribution of the ensemble is empirically derived from the distribution of the class votes from the trees that are part of the ensemble. The rest of this answer still holds though.

Comment: @ogrisel just found your comment. I am a bit confused, as `probability distribution of the ensemble is empirically derived from the distribution of the class votes from the trees that are part of the ensemble` in my view **is** what I called `can be reduced to regression of classes probabilities distribution`.

Comment: To me logistic regression is a model that explicitly does regression of the classes distribution and thus builds a classification model out of an inner regression model. Random Forest is doing the opposite: it builds a regression model (of the probability distribution) out of a bunch of "pure" classification models. Decision Trees from the CART family can be used to do regression but this not what is used to estimate the class probability assignment for a random forest.

Comment: hmm.. this makes sense. I wonder if I could use other regression algorithms the same way - except the tree based ones.. for example if I use `LassoLars`, fit it on the training set, could the prediction be used as a probability for the outcome(0.7 indicating a stronger chance of the sample belonging to the class 1.0)?